# Physical significance of positive group delay with negative phase delay

Tags: delay, low-pass, phase, phase-shift, high-pass-filter

This question is an addendum to: [Is group delay the same as the delay of a certain frequency?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393210/is-group-delay-the-same-as-the-delay-of-a-certain-frequency)

Lately, I've been going back to basics to better understand the concepts of group and phase delay, so I did some simulations with the following simple LPF and HPF:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEOb6D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the LPF the transfer function is:

$$H(jw)=\frac{\tau}{j\omega + \tau}$$

and for the HPF:

$$H(jw)=\frac{j\omega}{j\omega+\tau}$$

where \$ \tau=\frac{1}{RC}\$

In case of the LPF its group and phase delays are:

$$\tau_g(\omega)=-\frac{d\phi}{d\omega}=\frac{\tau}{\omega^2+\tau^2}$$

and

$$\tau_\phi=-\frac{\phi}{\omega}=\frac{\text{arctan}\left(\frac{\omega}{\tau}\right)}{\omega}$$

To get a better feel, I simulated in Multisim with the resistor and capacitor values of 1K and 1uF respectively, I exported the phase angle VS frequency values to an Excel spreadsheet to numerically check the results, I entered the formula for the phase delay and then I differentiated numerically to get the group delay, these are the graphs:

[image: LPF Group Delay]
[image: LPF Phase Delay]

Both graphs seem consistent with the analytical formulas.

Now for the HPF the group and phase delay are:

$$\tau_g(\omega)=-\frac{d\phi}{d\omega}=\frac{\tau}{\omega^2+\tau^2}$$

and

$$\tau_\phi=-\frac{\phi}{\omega}=\frac{\text{arctan}\left(\frac{\omega}{\tau}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\omega}$$

As you can see, the group delay for the HPF is the same as the group delay of the LPF, however the phase delay is different. Here are the simulated graphs

[image: HPF Group Delay]
[image]

So here is the question: What does it mean (in the time domain) to have an increasing negative phase delay while having a decreasing positive group delay?

The way I see it, is that the envelope of the output waveform is still lagging but the phase seems to be leading the input waveform?